# IIS7 - ASP- Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I have the following error:  Removed the resource you are looking for, has been renamed or is not available right now. I have installed IIS7 in a windows 7 64 bit. Im trying to run a ASP Classic project, but I dont get it runs.

Here is my problem

[image: Error Here]

I have my project in: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\101azafatas`

Here is another image

[image: Another Image]

Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
    Nota: como alternativa para editar manualmente este archivo puede utilizar la 
    herramienta Administración de sitios Web para configurar los valores de la aplicación. Utilice
    la opción Sitio Web->Configuración de Asp.Net en Visual Studio.
    Encontrará una lista completa de valores de configuración y comentarios en 
    machine.config.comments, que se encuentra generalmente en 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings />
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="101Azafatas" connectionString="Enlist=true;Max Pool Size = 1000; Min    Pool Size=0;integrated security=True;data source=SERVIDOR;persist security info=False;initial catalog=101Azafatas;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="100" />
        <!-- 
            Establezca debug="true" en la compilación para insertar símbolos 
            de depuración en la página compilada. Dado que este proceso 
            afecta al rendimiento, debe establecer este valor como true 
            durante la depuración.

            Opciones de Visual Basic:
            Establezca strict="true" para no permitir las conversiones de todos los tipos de datos 
            donde se pueda producir una pérdida de datos. 
            Establezca explicit="true" para forzar la declaración de todas las variables.
        -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
                <add assembly="Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /></assemblies></compilation>
        <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false">
            <namespaces>
                <clear />
                <add namespace="System" />
                <add namespace="System.Collections" />
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
                <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
                <add namespace="System.Text" />
                <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
                <add namespace="System.Web" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Caching" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Security" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Profile" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <!--
            La sección <authentication> permite configurar 
            el modo de autenticación de seguridad utilizado por 
            ASP.NET para identificar a un usuario entrante. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
              <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="index.aspx" defaultUrl="interior.aspx" />
        </authentication>
        <!--
            La sección <customErrors> permite configurar 
            las acciones que se deben llevar a cabo/cuando un error no controlado tiene lugar
            durante la ejecución de una solicitud. Específicamente, 
            permite a los desarrolladores configurar páginas de error html 
            que se mostrarán en lugar de un seguimiento de pila de errores.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler,System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="74.54.202.242" port="25" defaultCredentials="false" userName="gestoria@101azafatas.com" password="acer" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does `Index.asp` exist in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\101azafatas`?, my guess would be no...

Comment: Wait a minute with your [latest edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24820554/5) it looks like you are dealing with an ASP.Net application not a Classic ASP application is this the case? It's not helping that you're not making it very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. You're trying to go to a page that doesn't exist. If you got there through a link, double-check that it's pointing in the right place. If you typed the address yourself, look at your server files and see what you meant.

Comment: It is an old project in ASP

Comment: I mean that your image said `/index.asp`, and that might be the case, but I want to make sure you don't mean `/index.aspx`, because that could cause this problem.

Comment: Alright, just making sure. So you're sure the file exists? And also, how old a project is it?

Comment: files exist in the path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\101azafatas. About 2005-2006

Comment: Are you running this directly from the file system, or through IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: I have installed all components of IIS7

Comment: Hmm. You're sure the file is in the VS project? That's worth checking as well. And did this file ever work? Since you say it's such an old project, was this file always associated and it stopped working, or did you just add it?

Comment: I just added it. It is actually working in localhost in another machine. But I dont manage that machine where is running

Comment: The plot thickens. Do you have IIS Express on the machine? I wonder if you could run it in that instead, where you might not have the same configuration set.

Comment: Ok, Im going to install IIS Express in my machine to try it

Comment: @j_arab Does `/Index.asp` attempt a `Response.Redirect()`? Possibly the page it's trying to redirect to cannot be found.

Comment: I inserted another image more

Comment: @j_arab That image is a ASP.Net Web Application compile error are you dealing with Classic ASP or ASP.Net which is it?

Answer (score 0):

As you have confirmed that `/Index.asp` exists in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\101azafatas` the `HTTP 404 Not Found` must be being generated by something else.

The IIS message returns `Index.asp` as the calling page which suggests that something in that page is producing the `HTTP 404 Not Found`.

Common reason for this is the use of;

```vb
'Attempt to redirect to non-existent page test.asp.
Call Response.Redirect("test.asp")
```

In the above instance the IIS Server will issue a [`HTTP 302 Found`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) passing `test.asp` as the new location. The problem is when the browser then requests `test.asp` and IIS doesn't know about it (as it doesn't exist), it returns `HTTP 404 Not Found` in response.